# CAN I USE TWO LM2678 REGULATOR IN PARALLEL? FOR TAKİNG 10A (5A+5A)

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator, high-current

[image]

I made a power card.there are 3 lm2678 regulator on card like webench png bottom.I want to connect two lm2678 output parallel for 5a+5a=10a.Is it true a way? is there a problem?

Comment: Yes, there will be a problem. One will try and supply all the current and the other will sit there thinking it's on a light load.

Comment: In general you can only safely parallel regulator circuits (or complete power supplies) if they were designed for that type of service (which will be a highlighted feature on the datasheet).

Comment: CAN YOU EDIT YOUR TITLE SO YOU ARE NOT SHOUTING AT US? Please.

Comment: They are not perfectly equal, so some unwanted current will go between. You may divide load and feed separately with same common wire.

Comment: Either use two 5A supplies to two different circuits (can share same ground only) and be mindful of startup timing differences, or choose a single regulator rated for 10A.

Comment: that schematic comes straight out of TI's design tool – why not ask the design tool what it would do to achieve a 10A output current?

Comment: @MarcusMüller i know asking to TI but they answer so late .

Comment: that schematic is from their online **tool**. You used their tool to design a 5A regulator. Now use it to design a 10 A regulator.

Comment: Please [edit] to remove the SHOUTING from your question title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two DC/DC converters in parallel, but you have to parallel the whole circuit, not just the IC and you will have to have some circuitry to balance the output current.

If you just parallel the two ICs, then the circuit will not work, as the ICs will not run in lock-step. There will be inevitably a time when one is conducting while the other is not, totally confusing the control loop of both, causing the whole thing to output some random voltage (frying what ever it powers) and potentially causing the whole thing to oscillate.

If you put two complete circuits in parallel without a current balancer, then you will have uneven load distribution and potentially one carrying 8A while the other does only 2A, leading to overheating and thus a thermal shutdown. At which point one will have to carry the whole 10A, which will immediately lead to a thermal shutdown too.

Generally, it's a bad idea to parallel DC/DC converters. The effort you need to put into to make it work properly is much larger than just getting a DC/DC converter that can cope with the load. At 10A, you probably wont be able to use a monolithic DC/DC converter with an on-die switch. But with an external FET you can switch almost any current. At this current I would go with a synchronous converter, as they have lower losses. There are many of those and the TI website will happily give you a selection of those available. One choice with the same input voltage range as the LM2678 would be the LM25145.

As you seem to be new to DC/DC converters, I would like to stress that you need to have a good understanding of EMI and how to layout DC/DC converters. If you do not, you will not fullfil EMI requirements, cause massive radiated power and not pass EMI/EMC testing/certification. The TI datasheets are usually a decent place to start at, but not all of them have the right layout. Some of them are even plain wrong and will cause more radiated power than need to be. Thus I suggest that you head over to youtube and watch some videos from experts, like e.g., Rick Hartley to learn how it is correctly done.